# Create list of objects

Tags: f#

Wondering how to create a list of instantiated objects

I have this

```
type myType = GoodState | BadState

let create =
    seq {for i in 1 .. 100000 do yield new myType}
```

this doesnt seem to work

anyone know a way of doing this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myType is a Discriminated Union, so you have to choose one of the options.

```
type myType = GoodState | BadState

//using your syntax to create a sequence of BadState
let create1 = seq{for _ in 1 .. 100000 do BadState} //yield is not required anymore

//another syntax to create a list of GoodState
let create2 = List.init 100000 (fun _ -> GoodState)
```

By the way, I used an underline "_" because I'm not using the index in this example, but you could replace for a variable name if you inted to use it for something.

Comment: `create1` is not a list, which may perhaps still cause problems for OP. I suggest adding `|> Seq.toList` following the sequence expression.

Comment: But an alternative is of course to simply use a list expression, so perhaps add that too.

Answer (score 1):

You construct values of `myType` using one of the two constructors you defined - `GoodState` and `BadState`. Neither have any arguments so you create values with:

```
let good : myType = GoodState
let bad : myType = BadState
```

You can construct a sequence of such values with e.g.

```
let create = seq {for i in 1 .. 100000 do yield GoodState}
```